# UIButton calling selector crashes the app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

In my app I've got a button which is an instance variable declared in the .h file already. 
Now after allocating it an assigning at target to it and actually pressing the button, the app crashes giving me following output in the debugger:

```
-[__NSCFString handleActionSheet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9090330
2012-05-04 17:51:02.646 financeAppV2[2595:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString handleActionSheet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9090330'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13d1022 0x1562cd6 0x13d2cbd 0x1337ed0 0x1337cb2 0x13d2e99 0x1e14e 0x1e0e6 0xc4ade 0xc4fa7 0xc3d8a 0x2dfa1a 0x13a599e 0x133c640 0x13084c6 0x1307d84 0x1307c9b 0x12ba7d8 0x12ba88a 0x1b626 0x29dd 0x2945)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

My code looks like following:

```
saveButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[saveButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"intervalbutton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[saveButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"intervalbuttonpressed"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
saveButton.alpha=.8;
saveButton.frame= frame;
UILabel* label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, saveButton.frame.size.width, 21)];
[saveButton addSubview:label];

[saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[self.view addSubview:saveButton];


-(void)handleActionSheet:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"working");
```

}

Any ideas why the app could be crashing?

Comment: Does that still happen if you comment out `[saveButton addSubview:label];`?

Comment: Yes it does. In fact I even get a stranger error:

-[_UITableViewSeparatorView handleActionSheet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a89a30
2012-05-04 18:12:52.485 financeAppV2[2997:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UITableViewSeparatorView handleActionSheet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a89a30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13d1022 0x1562cd6 0x13d2cbd 0x1337ed0 0x1337cb2 0x13d2e99 0x1e14e 0x1e0e6 0xc4ade 0xc4fa7 0xc3d8a 0x2dfa1a 0x13a599e 0x133c640 0x13084c6 0x1307d84 0x1307c9b 0x12ba7d8 0x12ba88a 0x1...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code it's difficult to be specific, but `self` is not correctly being retained.

You set up your button correctly (as far as I can see) and point the target to `self`. Unfortunately, by the time you press the button `self` has gone out of scope and the same memory is used by an `NSString`. iOS gets surprised when you send a string the `handleActionSheet:` message.

Comment: What indicates to you that `self` isn't properly retained? Could be a couple of other things, too, right?

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I actually found out what went wrong through your guidance. 
The viewcontroller in which my button was placed was not an instance variable. That is why I think ARC released it too early. I made a property for that viewcontroller and then it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a message named `initAllIVars:` to an `__NSCFString` object (likely an `NSString`).

Do a search for that message and try to figure out why the object receiving the message is an `NSString`.

Comment: I just edited the post and put in  a different selector to be called. However the same error message appears but with the updated selector instead. It is also a mystery to me why NSString is getting the message sent and not the UIButton

Comment: Whenever an object suddenly "changes types", it usually indicates that you've over-released that object and the memory is being re-used by something else. Set a breakpoint in your code and check the memory address of `saveButton` **before** adding it to `[self view]`. Then, check to see if at least it's the same memory address throwing the exception. If so, you've got a memory bug to track!

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code and it works. Maybe the frame it's not properly set

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIButton *saveButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    saveButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [saveButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"intervalbutton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [saveButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"intervalbuttonpressed"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    saveButton.alpha=.8;
    saveButton.frame= CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 40);
    UILabel* label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, saveButton.frame.size.width, 21)];
    label.text = @"Hello";
    [saveButton addSubview:label];

    [saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [self.view addSubview:saveButton];

}

-(void)handleActionSheet:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"working");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your test. The thing is I was porting the app to the iPad and simply copied the code which actually was working on the iPhone. But suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Failure to set the frame would not cause an object to be prematurely deallocated.